# How to subscribe to Tensorflow mailing lists without Google account?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to join some of the [Tensorflow mailing lists](https://www.tensorflow.org/community/lists), however the link directs to a google page which apparently requires a Google account to subscribe. I found [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-can-i-subscribe-to-a-google-mailing-list-with-a-non-google-e-mail-address) related answer, on how to join Google mailing lists without a Google account, however it can't figure out what the groupname for the Tensorflow lists is.

Comment: The mailing lists are Google Groups, so you need an account to subscribe. See [Find and join a group](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1067205). You can get release notifications by watching the repository on GitHub (or subscribing to the RSS feed of releases), and you can also watch [tensorflow/community](https://github.com/tensorflow/community) for other stuff.

Comment: @jdehesa So your saying it is simply impossible to join the mailing lists without a Google account. :-/

Comment: Well after reading the post that you linked I'm not sure if there may still be some "trick", I just meant according to Google you are supposed to have an account to subscribe.